# javascript/youtube api check state for playback restrictions

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

---

### javascript/youtube api check state for playback restrictions

---

*The problem is that i embed from gdata/youtube-api and sometimes it returns playback
video restrictions or embed not allowed. So i was checking for a state or something
to handle this. i tried adding the &format=5. & tried the -1 event.
With no luck. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) { if(event.data == -1){//rest of code}}
Thanks in advance.*

**Edit3/Solution to this problem: as you have the onError set to a function in that function
capture event and check for error was a solution to this problem.
    function onPlayerError(event) {if(event.data === 150 || event.data === 101) {//rest here}}**

*EDIT: adding more of the code.
EDIT 2: errorcode matching is the answer the only problem now is that i don't
know how to capture just the errorcode any ideas ?*

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="560" height="50" src="'.$striphttp.'"></iframe>



  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 1,'autohide':1,'wmode':'opaque' },
      //videoId: 'JW5meKfy3fY',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
        'onError': onPlayerError
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerError(event) {
  window.location.href = "#";

  }


  function onPlayerReady(event) { 
    //event.target.mute();
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data == 0) {
            window.location.href = "#";
            //location.reload();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load the json data about the video before trying to embed and check the restrictions:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&q=TJC-subagTg';

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        console.log(response.data.items[0].accessControl);
        console.log(response.data.items[0].restrictions);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

http://embed.plnkr.co/P6LqDCdPgTH0HiU3SReR/preview

Comment: i do parse the json data via php while handling the player side via javascript/iframe(embed). i do have a playerReady function so i could maybe do a check for the restrictions & accessControl via that way. it is as you suggest just inside already set function.

Comment: I would have to see your code to be able to help any further. The example you posted in your original post is not enough for me to go off of.

Comment: i added more of the code so you can see what i'm working with.

Comment: If you are already loading the JSON on the server side(PHP) I would do the restriction check there and prevent any of the embed javascript from executing for that specific video if it matches your conditions.

Comment: did read that it catches an error of 150 on all of those restricted etc, i did an onError: onPlayerError and then ifcheck on errorCode == 150 but it does not fire so i guess i'm not setting the error check right. any ideas on that ?

Comment: Not sure exactly where the errorCode comes in but if you do a console.log on event in your error handler you should be able to see how to access the error code, likely something like this:
function onPlayerError(event) {
  if(event.data === 150 || event.data === 101){
    //whatever you want to do here.
  }
}

Comment: You should post the answer you came up with so that anybody else who comes across this question knows where to go.

Glad you got it sorted.